# Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory (ASP.NET webforms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET webforms project with a master page using adminlte UI.

I created a web site with default project in Visual Studio and then change the project to apply adminlte dashboard, copied all scripts and bootstrap then change master page and default form.

My problem: in menu sidebar when I tried to add from to root folder and do this

```
<li>
  <a runat="server" href="Shipment.aspx">
    <i class="fa fa-th"></i><span>Shipment</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

everything is ok and form loads without any problem.

But when I created a folder `Track` and created a new form inside it and try to do this

```
<li>
  <a runat="server" href="~/Track/Shipment.aspx">
    <i class="fa fa-th"></i><span>Shipment</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

I get this exception:

[exception](http://pastebin.ca/3961517)

What I tried

First attempt:

```
<li>
  <a runat="server" href="../../Shipment.aspx">
    <i class="fa fa-th"></i><span>Shipment</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Second attempt:

```
<li>
  <a runat="server" href="../Track/Shipment.aspx">
    <i class="fa fa-th"></i><span>Shipment</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Third attempt:

```
<li>
  <a runat="server" href="~/../Shipment.aspx">
    <i class="fa fa-th"></i><span>Shipment</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Final attempt:

```
<li>
  <a runat="server" href=~/Track/Shipment.aspx">
    <i class="fa fa-th"></i><span>Shipment</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: The folder i created is folder under project root it's a sub directory folder

Comment: Post (relevant part of) exceptions in the actual question, not as a link.

Comment: Post the results of attempts 2-final. That last one ought to work, what is the error?

Comment: Can we see the path the the menu user control in your master page(s)?

Comment: @HenkHolterman i didn't know ho to do this ,every time i put it in the question i got message that my question has code not formatted well

Comment: @HenkHolterman every attempt i got the same exception

Comment: @IrishChieftain my menu doesn't build as user control i build it traditionally and with some css

Comment: I think we need to see the structure of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed some deprecated and superfluous markup - adjust any related CSS selectors.

Try this:

```
<li>
  <a runat="server" href="~/Shipment.aspx">
    <em class="fa fa-th">Shipment</em>
  </a>
</li>
```

The "~/" should resolve anything from the main project root down, presuming there are no page name conflicts. Some of your attempts should have worked so I'm thinking maybe something else is causing a problem. Presuming your menu is in a User Control, maybe it's the path to this control in your Master Page(s) that is causing the problem?

Comment: Post the error messages. I think it's obvious at this point that you're not giving us enough information.